# Built-in module for bayesian curve fitting in python

Tags: python, scipy

I was searching scipy library for any built in modules for Bayesian curve fitting and I'm not able to find one. All I found is :
[scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)

But the description of this link says that this is non linear least squares fit. My question is - do we have to implement our own module for Bayesian curve fitting or is there any such module that I might have missed?

Answer (score 3):

Bayesian inference is not part of the SciPy library - it is simply out of scope for `scipy`. There is a number of separate python modules that deal with it, and it seems that you have indeed missed quite a few of those - most notably implementations of Markov chain Monte Carlo algorithms [`pymc`](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/) and [`emcee`](http://dan.iel.fm/emcee/current/) that are probably the most used MCMC packages. They are both relatively straightforward to set up, but in my opinion `emcee` is easier to get started with.

As with everything, the devil is in the details with Bayesian curve fitting - I highly recommend reading through [this overview](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/06/14/frequentism-and-bayesianism-4-bayesian-in-python/) to get a feel of subtleties of line fitting.